# How to check repeat customers in Magento?

Tags: customer-account, magento-ce, purchase-order

Need a data which shows the name of the repeat customer and total purchase made by her/him in Magento backend.

Comment: Please see my anser hope it help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use magento's report to get all data of customer. Number of order by customer and total spent of customer. You can also get information what they have in cart now. your sell for current month etc.

You need to goto in admin panel. You can see `Reports` menu wwhere you can find all related report. for customer data you need to check `Reports->Customers`

See below screenshot

[image]

Comment: I know I'm bumping an old question, but that report only shows you the top 5,  anyway of expanding that?

Comment: @PaddyD see this answer. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82033/customers-by-orders-total-only-shows-5